# Django view function execution jumps to different function

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm adding new applications to an existing Django project, and encountered something I am unable to debug.  The callback error is "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'META'", but I'm not sure that's what's going on.  I've written 4 of these apps for different API objects today, and had no issues.  When I add print() debug messages to the functions, what I find is that the execution seems to be jumping out of my lead_lists view function and into my lists view function before it errors.

This is my list.views.py

```py
def list(request):
    print("we're in lists view")
    lists = List.objects.all()
    print("lists saved for context")
    context = {'lists': lists}
    print("context created")
    return render(request, 'list.html', context) # fails here

def load_lists(request):
    api_lists = services.get_lists()
    print("api lists loaded")
    db_list_ids = list(List.objects.values_list('list_id', flat=True)) # jumps out of function here
    print("db lists loaded") # this never prints
    print(f"db_list_ids: {db_list_ids}")
    for api_list in api_lists:
        if api_list['id'] not in db_list_ids:
            api_list = services.transform_list(api_list)
            form = ListModelForm(api_list)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save
            else:
                return HttpResponse(form.errors)
    print("exited load loop")
    lists = List.objects.all()
    print("load lists objects saved")
    context = {'lists': lists}
    print("load lists context saved")
    return render(request, 'load_lists.html', context)
```

The expected result is, when I navigate to /list/load it runs the load_lists view function.  Here is the output I get from the console.

```sh
we're in lists view
lists saved for context
context created
[31/Jul/2019 16:20:32] "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2458
api lists loaded
we're in lists view
lists saved for context
context created
Internal Server Error: /list/load/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\ongage\list\views.py", line 19, in load_lists
    db_list_ids = list(List.objects.values_list('list_id', flat=True))
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\ongage\list\views.py", line 14, in list
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "c:\users\david.wilcox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 246, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "C:\Users\David.Wilcox\ongage-django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py", line 40, in debug
    if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'META'
[31/Jul/2019 16:20:36] "GET /list/load/ HTTP/1.1" 500 103930
```

I originally thought it wasn't playing nicely due to the usage of the word 'list', so I refactored and renamed my variables, but the error is the same.

Comment: You have overwritten the `list` builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: please do *not* name your views after Python builtins like `list`. You can rename the view function to `view_lists`.

You here defined a function named list. As a result, if you later use `list(List.objects.values_list('list_id', flat=True))` in your `load_lists` view, you will indeed call the view function, and not the builtin function, since that identifier now points to your view function.

You can for example rename it to `view_lists`, like:

```
# rename view function

def view_lists(request):
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'lists': List.objects.all()})

def load_lists(request):
    api_lists = services.get_lists()
    db_list_ids = list(List.objects.values_list('list_id', flat=True))
    print(f"db_list_ids: {db_list_ids}")
    for api_list in api_lists:
        if api_list['id'] not in db_list_ids:
            api_list = services.transform_list(api_list)
            form = ListModelForm(api_list)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponse(form.errors)
    lists = List.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'load_lists.html', context = {'lists': lists})
```

Note that you need to call the `save()` function on your form, so `form.save()`, *not* <s>`form.save`</s>.

[**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) recommends adding a trailing underscore if there is no better name than a builtin one:

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to **append a single trailing underscore** rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus `class_` is better than `clss`. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)
>
> (...)
>
> If your public attribute name **collides with a reserved keyword, append a single trailing underscore to your attribute name**. This is preferable to an abbreviation or corrupted spelling. (However, notwithstanding this rule, 'cls' is the preferred spelling for any variable or argument which is known to be a class, especially the first argument to a class method.)

Comment: Thank you!  Super obvious, but I was staring at it too long.  What is the pythonic way to name functions and variables when you are dealing with external objects that share a name with python builtins?

Comment: @d-wilcox: PEP-8 recommends adding a trailing inderscore.